# How to restore the Terminal mail program to default settings

Tags: terminal, email

So a number of months ago I was messing around in Terminal trying to get my Mac to send an email from the command line. Unfortunately, I don't remember everything I did but I know I was messing around with `postfix` and creating a sasl password file, etc. I never got it to work and gave up.

Now I want to try again but don't remember what I already did. Is there a way to restore `postfix` or the `mail` terminal programs to their default settings so I can get a fresh start?

Comment: did you ever get the terminal `mail` to work?

Answer (score 1):

There must be two files **main.cf.default** and **master.cf.default** which you can use to overwrite the messed up ones, thus resetting them to the distribution default values.

```
cp /etc/postfix/main.cf.default /etc/postfix/main.cf
cp /etc/postfix/master.cf.default /etc/postfix/master.cf
```

If you can't find the default ones, you may try to copy them from another computer.

Also, you may type `postconf -d` which will print main.cf default parameter settings instead of actual settings.  Specify -df to fold long lines for human readability (Postfix 2.9 and later). Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/postconf.1.html).